# Multiple iFrames & “104: Connection reset by peer”

Tags: php, html, security, nginx, iframe

I wonder if someone has happened to the following ...

Suppose we have domain A and B;

```
A -> homesite.com
B -> embedsite.com
```

If i insert several B iframes to A, the PHP service stop and show error 104: Restore the connection in pairs.

However, when we do the same, but when i assign a different "id" to each iframe, then the service works.

What can be happening? This is a iFrame Injection case? Would a solution be possible without the need to add "id" in the iframes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see why the service crash occurs.

The javascript codes that are inside the iframes, request the resource in asynchronous form, and for this reason, the PHP service can't attend the requests and derive the resources at the same time for each iframe.

After several tests, i understand which factors help to better assimilate the situation and solve the problem, I detail them below;

> - Add "id" to the "iframe" tags.
> - Avoid the attribute "async" in the "script" javascript declaration, or libraries that load the resources in this way.
> - In the PHP service, change the service by TCP, instead of socket. ("file.sock" to "127.0.0.1:9000")
> - Increase waiting times related to requests (in the web service, apache, nginx, etc.)

A greeting